# Copying the last row of data only from Excel to Word

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to write a code that will only copy the last row of data from a spreadsheet to bookmarks in a Word document. It all works perfectly apart from the fact I can't work out how to only get it to choose the last row - in the code below the `For i=74 to r` it is manually set to the last row (74) to get data whilst I was testing.

```
   Dim objWord
   Dim objDoc
   Dim objRange

   Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")

   objWord.Visible = True


r = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 74 To r
        With Cells(i, 5)
           If .Value = "Mobile Plant" Then
                Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Add(Template:="S:\......docx", NewTemplate:=False, DocumentType:=0)

    Set objRange = objDoc.Bookmarks("LicenceNo").Range
    objRange.InsertAfter Cells(i, 4)

    Set objRange = objDoc.Bookmarks("Date").Range
    objRange.InsertDateTime DateTimeFormat:="d/M/yyyy"

    Set objRange = objDoc.Bookmarks("Name").Range
    objRange.InsertAfter Cells(i, 7)

    Set objRange = objDoc.Bookmarks("Company").Range
    objRange.InsertAfter Cells(i, 6)

    Set objRange = objDoc.Bookmarks("Location").Range
    objRange.InsertAfter Cells(i, 11)

    Set objRange = objDoc.Bookmarks("Location2").Range
    objRange.InsertAfter Cells(i, 10)

    Set objRange = objDoc.Bookmarks("From").Range
    objRange.InsertAfter Cells(i, 16)

    Set objRange = objDoc.Bookmarks("To").Range
    objRange.InsertAfter Cells(i, 17)

    Set objRange = objDoc.Bookmarks("Date2").Range
    objRange.InsertDateTime DateTimeFormat:="d/M/yyyy"

        End If
        End With

    Next i

    End Sub
```

Comment: If you want only the last row, why are you using a for loop?

Comment: I'd amended previous code I've used in other spreadsheets, I'm picking this up as I go along so I stuck with what I had working.

Comment: @AAA I've only just managed to try it, and still not working having amended it to "Table5" (the table name). Have also tried changing it to start from column E (5) and nothing.

Comment: what is the issue? What is the value of i when you step through it?

Comment: @AAA Same as before, the value is 1003 and won't open anything - if I change it to start from column E (5) it changes to 74 which is the actual final row but even though the cell value is "Mobile Plant" it won't open Word etc

Comment: Step through the code to the `If` line and check the value of the cell in the Locals Window. Also can you send me this sheet?

Comment: Apologies, hadn't managed to access the spreadsheet until this morning. I've ended up using the For loop so it checks for any value in column F, and if there's anything in there it will copy the values to Word.

Answer (score 0):

Following will return you the last used row index in the sheet:

```
Set Sheet = ActiveSheet
LastRowIndex = Sheet.Cells.Find("*", searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row
```

Answer (score 0):

After a whole dialog, we are finally able to decipher the *major* reason you couldn't get the last row with the above code. When you have a table, that code would return the very last row in the table, *because it contains a table!*

We have to search within the appropriate column of the table, in a different manner, instead:

```
Sub Test()

Dim objWord, objDoc, objRange, i As Long

'Change both sheet and tables names accordingly
'Also I assume the last row of the first column of the table is same for Col. E
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Licences").ListObjects("Table1").ListColumns(1).Range
    i = .Find(What:="*", _
          After:=.Cells(1), _
          LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
          SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
          SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
          MatchCase:=False).Row

    If .Cells(i, 5).Value = "Mobile Plant" Then
        Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
        objWord.Visible = True
        Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Add(Template:="S:\......docx", NewTemplate:=False, DocumentType:=0)
        Set objRange = objDoc.Bookmarks("LicenceNo").Range
        objRange.InsertAfter .Cells(i, 4)

        Set objRange = objDoc.Bookmarks("Date").Range
        objRange.InsertDateTime DateTimeFormat:="d/M/yyyy"

        Set objRange = objDoc.Bookmarks("Name").Range
        objRange.InsertAfter .Cells(i, 7)

        Set objRange = objDoc.Bookmarks("Company").Range
        objRange.InsertAfter .Cells(i, 6)

        Set objRange = objDoc.Bookmarks("Location").Range
        objRange.InsertAfter .Cells(i, 11)

        Set objRange = objDoc.Bookmarks("Location2").Range
        objRange.InsertAfter .Cells(i, 10)

        Set objRange = objDoc.Bookmarks("From").Range
        objRange.InsertAfter .Cells(i, 16)

        Set objRange = objDoc.Bookmarks("To").Range
        objRange.InsertAfter .Cells(i, 17)

        Set objRange = objDoc.Bookmarks("Date2").Range
        objRange.InsertDateTime DateTimeFormat:="d/M/yyyy"
    End If
End With

End Sub
```